# How to CSS background-image wobble

Tags: css

How can I make the background image of my site wobble to create a bit of motion, without leaving empty space at the edges of the screen?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_shake_image.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set values for the background-position CSS property.

```js
"use strict";

var curStep = 0, interval=null;

window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);
function onLoaded(evt)
{
    interval = setInterval(onInterval, 1000/60);
}

function onInterval(evt)
{
    curStep++;
    curStep &= 0xFF;    // max value of 255
    
    let angle = (curStep / 255) * 2*Math.PI;
    let value = Math.sin(angle) * 10;
    
    let tgt = document.querySelector('div');
    tgt.style.backgroundPosition = `130px ${110+value.toFixed(0)}px`;
}
```

```css
.test
{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/pineapple.jpg);
    background-position: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You don't need javascript. You can do it the classic way with html/css only ... Just use/add a background-layer (NOT: background-image!) to your element. Move your background-image to that layer-element (= use it as background there) and let the background-layer-element wobble i.e. with the animation from w3schools.

**Have fun:**

*(Note: the background layer in the example is flexible. It adapts width an height from the parent elements automatically. See changing sizes when you open it to full page. So you can use any image as background image as you would have done it on the parent element. In this example `background-size` has been set to `cover`. Just try it yourself.)*

**[UPDATE]**

I have been a little bit to fast ... I did not appreciate your question to fullfill complete background on the first approach. I added negative values to `position: absolute` of background layer. Now the background image is a little bit larger than the parent element and does not leave space free when wobbeling.

In the demonstration you now see parent element marked by the red border.

To avoid overlapping effect set `overflow: hidden` so parent element when using the code (see in code example).

```css
/* wobble css */
.wobbled-background {
  position: relative;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

.background-layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  margin: auto;

  /*
  EXAMPLE IS DEMO
  WHEN USE SET OVERLOW TO HIDDEN:
  overflow: hidden;
  */

  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/400x300/30b5c7/d0f288&text=-+BACKGROUND+IMAGE+-");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-animation: shake 0.5s;
          animation: shake 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
            transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
            transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
            transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
            transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);
            transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
            transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
            transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
            transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
            transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
            transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
            transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);
            transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
            transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
            transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wobbled-background">

    <div class="background-layer"></div>

    <p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie.
    Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, 
    musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular.</p>

    <p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie.
    Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, 
    musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
   @keyframes wobble {
   0% { transform: translateX(0%); } 
   15% { transform: translateX(-25%) rotate(-5deg); } 
   30% { transform: translateX(20%) rotate(3deg); } 
   45% { transform: translateX(-15%) rotate(-3deg); } 
   60% { transform: translateX(10%) rotate(2deg); }
   75% { transform: translateX(-5%) rotate(-1deg); }
   100% { transform: translateX(0%); }
```

}